# Stuck on combinatorial proof that $\binom{w}{p} \binom{p}{m} = \binom{w}{m} \binom{w-m}{p-m}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I'm in an introductory discrete mathematics course and i'm having a lot of trouble with this proof. I'm not sure if i'm heading in the right direction or not but I used the fact that $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and started trying to algebraically reduce them to eachother but haven't succeeded. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The algebraic reduction should be straightforward - i.e. just write everything in terms of factorials and both sides should equal $\frac{w!}{(w-p)!m!(p-m)!}$

Comment: Wow you are right I accidentally wrote $\binom{p}{m} = \frac{p!}{m!(p-w)!}$ and never checked that part (at the beginning) thanks so much.